# Is there a way to extract only desired text from an image?

Tags: python, android-studio, machine-learning, ocr, python-tesseract

I am working on a project where I am trying to extract the medicine name just by scanning the entire medicine packet. For example -

Below is the image consisting of the tablet information named 'Health OK'.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuY9k.jpg]

My question is whether, by scanning or by using this image, is it possible to extract only the name of the tablet i.e. 'Health OK' ?

I've tried using Pytesseract but it didn't provide me with desired results. Below is the code -

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract, re
f = "ocr.jpg"
t = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(f))
print(t)
m = re.findall(r"[\d—-]+ TABLETS [\d—-]+", t)
if m:
    print(m[0])
```

Is there any possible solution using ANN or CNN models?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Let’s say in this image we use the context “large letters in a blue box” to determine the product name. What are the chances all your other medicine labels use the same context to help you find the product name?

Comment: @MarkNeal I thought of it before, like extracting only text with large font than other text, but confused whether how can I implement it

Answer (score 0):

My take on this would be to create a variable for the desired text that you want to extract. Once you run an OCR on an image, store its output in a list as well. 
For example:

```
disired_text = 'Health OK'
OCR_output = ['Multivitamin', 'Multiminerals', 'Amino Acids', 'with Taurine', 'Health OK']
```

Once you have these lists, you can use any string matching algorithm like fuzzy matching to extract the best match from the **OCT_output list**
For Example:

```
score_dict = {} #initializing dictionary to store text and score
for output_text in OCR_output:
    score = fuzzy_match_function(output_text, desired_text)
    score_dict[output_text] = score
```

You will get a score_dict (a dictionary) containing text and scores. You can extract the one that has the minimum distance with your desired variable.

Hope this works out for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can train a model if you have sufficient samples by marking the area of text of interest to extract or recognize the area then feeding that area to OCR for extraction  .
From what i see neural network if you have enough data to train on. Probably you can use some sort of transfer learning on an already trained model.
if you don't have labeled data, you can use commercially available annotation tools to mark the area of interest for training.